# How to read spark-submit parameters from file when submitting spark job?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am currently writing a spark streaming application that requires multiple dependencies and configurations. Right now, I have to run my spark job with the following code:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.6,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.4.6 --conf spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll --conf spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll mongodbtest.py
```

It works, but is quite a cumbersome command to submit, and I would like to place these dependencies somewhere where I can simply run

```
spark-submit mongodbtest.py
```

I already tried specifying `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` in `os.environ` as follows:

```py
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--conf spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll ' \
                                    '--conf spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/test.coll' \
                                    '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.4.6'
```

But running `spark-submit mongodbtest.py` with the above line included in the python file results in the following error:

```
________________________________________________________________________________________________
  Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

  1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
     spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.4.6 ...

  2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
     Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, Version = 2.4.6.
     Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar> ...

________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

and the job fails. Where can I include the configuration and dependency information so that I don't have to include all of this info every time I submit the spark job on the command line? Thank you.

Comment: Have you explored [Apache Livy](https://livy.apache.org/)? It's a better way to submit spark apps where you create a json file for all the props & submit the job over a HTTP request.

Comment: FWIW, if you want to use Kafka and Mongo, it would make more sense to use Structured Streaming, or spark-sql-kafka dependency

Comment: `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` should work, but it needs to be loaded before you create a SparkSession